# How to calculate the number of paychecks from hire date?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to calculate the number of paychecks (biweekly) if I only know the most recent pay date, and the date of hire? I will greatly appreciate if you can help me.

Here is an example:

Hire date: 02/06/2019
Last payday: Friday 11/01/2019
Biweekly, gets paid every other Friday.
What is the number of paydays in between? 
Counting manually, the answer is 20.

How do I know that using Excel?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

subtract the two dates and divide by 14 and add 1:

```
=INT((A2-A1)/14)+1
```

[image]

Comment: Terrific! Simple and time saver! Thank you Scott Craner!

Comment: Could you tell me how to lock the formula in C1, as well?

Comment: What do you mean "Lock"?

Comment: I might no be using the right term. I mean, to prevent anybody from erasing/changing the formula accidentally, since I will be sharing the spreadsheet.

Comment: riht click the cell and choose cell format.  Under protection make sure it is checked Locked and the cells you want the user to be able to change are not locked.  then protect the worksheet.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: I did it weekly as well using your formula. Do you know how would it be for semi-monthly? Where people usually get paid on the 5th and 20th of the month.

Comment: That is a little more complicated.  feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: Sure! I greatly appreciate your kindness and clear answers. Best vibes!

Comment: This formula has been working great, still with a glitch though, and I need it to work 100% accurate, just I can't figure it out yet. For example: An employee is hired on 01/01/2019.  His last payday: 11/15/2019. Using the formula (paid biweekly) the answer shows he received 24 paychecks, but the reality is different (23). How could I customize it to prevent glitches in the 2019 calendar?

Comment: I get `23` with the formula, and with the count manually.  @stardust

Comment: See: https://imgur.com/S8lzDkM

Comment: I was missing something I forgot when increased the formula, I had this =IF(OR(C4="",D4=""),"",IF(D4=1,0,((D4-C4)/14)+1)), thank you again, it fixed it!